# Counting the number of surjective functions such that.....

Tags: combinatorics

I have troubles with this exercise:

Counting the number of surjective functions from $\{1,2,\ldots,10\}$ to $\{ 1, 2, \ldots, 9\}$ such that $f(2i+1)>f(2i-1)$  and $f(2i)>f(2i+2)$ for $i=1,2,3,4$.

Thanks,

Andrea

Comment: what do you know about surjective functions? What did you try?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The values on the odd numbers are distinct and in an increasing order. Same for the values on the even numbers.

**Hint:** If you know the 5 values of the odd numbers, and the 5 values of the even numbers, then the function is uniquely determined.

**Hint:** Since the function is surjective, there is exactly 1 value that is taken on twice.

**Hint:** There are 9 possibilities for the value that is taken on twice.

**Hint:** How many ways are there to pick the 5 values which form the image of the odd numbers? Note that this must include the value which is taken on twice.

Hence, there are $ 9 \times { 8 \choose 4} $ possibilities for the (multi-)set of the range.

Comment: I completely understand your first three hints but I can't  see why you wrote the fourth hint for the set of the range and I cannot complete the solution. I'm sorry but this exercise really put me in a tight spot. Could you give me some extra help?

Comment: @user119287 I broke it up into 2, which explains how to calculate it.

Comment: 10X(8 4) is the final answer or do i still miss something?

Comment: @MichaelJoyce Indeed. Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, I was having doubts about that number. Can somebody give a clear and ultimate explanation? This exercise is becoming hateful...

Comment: how can i have ten possibilities if the set is made of nine elements?

Comment: @user119287: The final answer is less important than understanding the reasoning that goes into the answer.  So you don't have a "final answer" until you fully comprehend all of the steps, some of which are subtle.  Use Calvin's very nicely constructed set of hints to figure out the answer.  If you're stuck, try to figure out a simpler problem, like counting all functions $f: \lbrace 1, 2, 3, 4 \rbrace \rightarrow \lbrace 1, 2, 3 \rbrace$ that satisfy $f(1) > f(3)$ and $f(2) > f(4)$. Calvin's method will still work for this simpler example and you'll be able to write out all the possibilities.

Comment: I apologize for my "editing" skills. I tried to solve the simpler example and I found that I can choose ( 3 2) for the odd numbers and 2 for the even ones. If I apply the same reasoning to the original problem I have (9 5) choices for the odd numbers but I still have troubles with the choices for the even ones..I still have some steps missing....

Comment: I maybe did it. I just tried all the possible values for f(1), such as 1,2,3,4,5. Given that I have 4 possible choices for the other increasing odd numbers left and since the function must be surjective the other even numbers have to be predetermined with only one even number that takes on one element twice. Following this lead I computed all the possible scenarios for f(1) and I finally found that it should be 5+5(5 4)+5(6 4)+5(7 4)+5(8 4). I hope I made myself clear and I hope I did it right. Thanks for your patience with me.

Andrea

Comment: @Andrea Do not focus on what $f(1) $ is. Let's say that the image of the function is the multi set  $\{1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 \} $. How many possibilities are there for $\{ f(1), f(3), f(5), f(7), f(9) \} $? Why must this set contain the number 3? Apart from there, are there any restrictions on the other 4 choices?

Comment: For f(1),f(3),f(5),f(7),f(9) I can choose (9 5) elements. And I have four remaining elements that are going to be the choices for four even elements upon 2,4,6,8,10. One of the even elements must take on one element that has been covered by an odd element upon 1,3,...,9 because the function is surjective. Then I computed all the possible choices given the restraint that f(1) cannot be bigger than 5 and given the order of f(2),f(4),..,f(10). Am I following the right path?